# Rangy ul-li highlighting issue

Tags: javascript, highlighting, rangy

I want to highlight word `This` in the li element of ul using Rangy:

```
<ul>
    <li>T<strong>hs is bea</strong>utiful.
    <br>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And at the run time I am ending up with a separate li wrapped surrounding the word `This` and another li wrapped surrounding the remaining contents `is beautiful`

How to stop adding a separate li tag around the word `This`

My code is as below :

```
$scope.highlightTagStrings=function() {
    var selection,selectedRange;
    selection = rangy.getSelection(); //console.log(rSel);
    var txt = selection.toHtml();
    selectedRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    selectedRange.deleteContents();
    //var node = selectedRange.createContextualFragment('<span class="hilite ' + evalNum + '" name="' + sSel + '~' + eSel + '">' + txt + '</span>');
    var node = selectedRange.createContextualFragment('<span style="background-color:pink" class="startIndex-' + startIndex + ' endIndex-' + endIndex + '">' + txt + '</span>');
    selectedRange.insertNode(node);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    return;
}
```

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no word "Ths" in your `li` element - it just looks that way.

Comment: So what to do in this case?

Comment: Does anyone know any solution?

Comment: is this what you're talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324813/jquery-change-color-of-string-in-a-text-ignoring-brs-between/39325246#39325246 basically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - Change Color of String in a Text, ignoring <br>'s between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324813/jquery-change-color-of-string-in-a-text-ignoring-brs-between)